# How big is an IP packet frame including headers?

Tags: udp

A bit of background.

I'm writing an application that uses UDP.  The application will run on a LAN (not internet).
I've been assuming that if my MTU is 1500 then thats how big a UDP payload can be, but I'm
not sure if the UDP header is meant to fit within that too.

I'm suspecting that if I send a UDP packet with a 1500 byte payload and the machine MTU is 1500 bytes will it end up sending two packets?

Searching the internet for a clear answer here seems harder than it should be, I've seen conflicting information.

Comment: Pretty sure that will give you fragmentation. You can use Wireshark to see this for sure though.

Comment: Thanks, yeah wireshark wasn't showing much because I am developing in isolation.  loopback MTU is 16436!

Comment: Thanks everyone, and thanks for the links.  They were better than the ones I found on google.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Ethernet  | IPv4         |UDP    | Data                   |Ethernet checksum|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  14 bytes    20 bytes     8 bytes    x bytes                4 bytes
           \ (w/o options)                               /
            \___________________________________________/
                              |
                             MTU
```

If your MTU is 1500, you have 1500-20-8 = 1472 bytes for your data.

- If you exceed that, the packets will be fragmented ,i.e. split into more packets.
- There might be more layers involved, e.g. 4 byte a vlan header if you're on top of a vlan ethernet.
- Some routers inbetween you and the destination might add more layers.

Comment: AFAIK the MTU does NOT include the Ethernet header and the trailing CRC32 (which you omitted), but is the effective Ethernet payload, where you have to subtract the IP protocol overhead.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I suspected but wasn't certain.

Comment: @Lucero Yes, you might be right, depending on which layer you define the MTU as. MTU of an IP datagram in this case I guess.

Comment: The MTU for Ethernet is the one we're talking about, so there is little speculation to which layer it applies.

Comment: Notable extra layer is subnetting, 8 bytes for 802.2 SNAP LLC.

Answer (score 3):

Yes your example would not fit in one frame.

The ethernet data payload is 1500 bytes. IPv4 requires a minimum of 20 bytes for its header. Alternatively IPv6 requires a minimum of 40 bytes. UDP requires 8 bytes for its header. That leaves 1472 bytes (ipv4) or 1452 (ipv6) for your data.

More information:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_II_framing
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Fixed_header
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

Answer (score -1):

So, here is how it works. Ethernet restricts your data flow to 1500 bytes per frame even though you have a 100 meg fat pipe. To really use the line rate, through your UDP application, you will need to use/move to ethernet jumbo frames which may support upto 9000 bytes per frame. Also, if you look at netflix/youtube and other streaming protocols, they test your link before they start streaming. What essentially they do is, they send some data to you and calculate/average the link speed before they dump the stream. They essentially use UDP as well but with a very big packet size. I guess bigger than 1500 bytes for sure.

Comment: That's called path MTU discovery and it's not nothing to do with my original question.  No point posting your answer given that the question was adequately answered well over 1 year ago. Think carefully before posting.